# Skipping task as it has no source files

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a task to create zip of the source Code:

```
import org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Zip
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction

class MakeJavadocZipTask extends Zip{
@TaskAction
def makeJavadocZip(){

     doFirst {
     baseName = project.componentUtils.getComponentName()
     version = project.componentUtils.getComponentVersion()
     classifier = 'javadocs'
 }

 from "${project.buildDir}/docs/javadoc"
 include '**/*'
 destinationDir project.file("${project.tmpDistLoc}/javadocs")  
}

}
```

This task when I run says UP TO DATE. I also tries using project.afterEvaluate closure, doesn't work. Any solutions

Comment: I am having a similar issue now.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This worked

```
class MakeJavadocZipTask extends Zip{
MakeJavadocZipTask(){
    doFirst {
        archiveName = project.componentUtils.getDistName('javadocs')
    }

    from "${project.buildDir}/docs/javadoc"
    include '**/*'
    destinationDir project.file("${project.tmpDistLoc}/javadocs")

}
```

}